# Does position imply existence?

Tags: existence, language

**People in that room don't exist.**

Is it contradictory because "people in that room" mean the people exist?

Does "in the room", "in the school", etc all imply the existence?

For example, "this car doesn't exist" is contradictory because "this" implies the car exists

Comment: "People in this room don't exist." sound weird in natural language. We usually say: "The room is empty."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm talking about logic...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm sorry that I'm poor at detailing something.

Comment: If you speak about "logic", you have to translate it into a logic formula. And this can be done in different way, like e.g. "the room is empty" that is **Room = ∅**. Alternatively, use suitable predicates and quantifiers.

Comment: No. Only propositions enter implications. "People in that room" and "this" are not propositions and do not imply anything at all until placed into one.

Comment: @Conifold Then, "people in that room don't exist" makes sense without being contradictory?

Comment: @Conifold Could you answer my question? Please.

Comment: On the face of it, "people in that room don't exist" is puzzling. But it could be taken to mean "there are no people in that room", or "anything in that room is not a person" or possibly, in some circumstances "there are only animals in that room".  I'm not sure whether that's enough to say it makes sense.

Comment: How about you think harder and answer your own question, considering that the answer is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

In *The Basic Problems of Phenomenology*, page 92, Heidegger writes:

> If we compare it with the Kantian thesis, the Thomistic thesis
> says—indeed, in agreement with Kant—that existence, there-being,
> actuality, is not a real predicate; it does not belong to the res of a
> thing but is nevertheless a res that is added on to the essentia [concept]. By
> means of his interpretation, on the other hand, Kant wishes to avoid
> conceiving of actuality, existence, itself as a res; he does this by
> interpreting existence as *relation* to the cognitive faculty, hence
> treating perception as position.

This is set out in Kant's [Critique of Pure Reason A598/B626](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4280/pg4280-images.html#linknote-67) (at page centre):

> Being is evidently not a real predicate, that is, a conception of
> something which is added to the conception of some other thing. It is
> merely the positing of a thing, or of certain determinations in it.
> Logically, it is merely the copula of a judgement.

That is, in making the judgement "people ***are*** in that room" they thereby exist in one's mind, which is the only reality one can be absolutely certain of.  The "*are*" constitutes the copula of a concept (people) plus predicate (in the room) brought to existence by the judgement.  Concept plus predicates is the constitution of a thing since Aristotle.  This Kantian form of existence applies to *things* observed, not the observer's mind.

OP: *Does "in the room", "in the school", etc all imply the existence?*

So no, they are predicates which would need to be joined to a concept in judgement for existence to be actualised.

It follows that "people ***are*** not in that room" asserts where people are not and does suggest that people might be elsewhere.  The statement "unicorns ***are*** not in that room" strikes one differently and prompts the objection that the concept is not realistic.

Comment: “People in that room don't exist" makes sense without being contradictory?

Comment: @Collins I just added on that point.  It does add extra considerations.

Comment: “People in that room don't exist" makes them seem like ghosts.

Comment: I mean it goes like this.

Comment: A: Do you know about the people in that room, they sleep every night.

Comment: B: The people in that room don't exist.

Comment: So B says the people that A speaks of do not exist. B disagrees with A or thinks A is mistaken.  Two different points of view.

Answer (score 0):

It is contradictory. “People in that room don’t exist.” means that people in that room are declared to have no existence whatsoever. If they have no existence then how did you define “people” ? They must be having at least physical attributes to be called “people”. If you want to say that the room is empty and you wish to emphasise that it is empty of people then you should say : The room is empty of people.